# Why can't objects instantiated during __init__ see their creator?

Tags: python, oop, instantiation, init

well I'm new to SO, OOP and python too, so please be gentle ;)

I've looked for threads and explainations related to this scoping issue elsewhere and haven't found any. I would be grateful for any assistance.

Sample code:

```
class Zeus(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name='zeus'
        self.maze=Maze()
        self.maze.get_zeus_name_1()
        self.maze.get_zeus_name_2(self)
        self.get_name_1()
        self.get_name_2(self)

    def get_name_1(self):
        try:
            print zeus.name
        except:
            print "impossible!?"

    def get_name_2(self,scope):
        print scope.name

class Maze(object):
    def get_zeus_name_1(self):
        try:
            print zeus.name
        except:
            print "can't be done!?"

    def get_zeus_name_2(self,scope):
        print scope.name

zeus=Zeus()
print 'now external calls:'
zeus.maze.get_zeus_name_1()
zeus.maze.get_zeus_name_2(zeus)
zeus.get_name_1()
zeus.get_name_2(zeus)
```

Output:

```
can't be done!?
zeus
impossible!?
zeus
now external calls:
zeus
zeus
zeus
zeus
```

During instantiation of `zeus`, if the `__init__` method creates an instance of another class, `maze`, this new instance is not able to access its creator object, `zeus` (unless `self` is passed to it).
(Additionally, if the `__init__` method calls a method within its own class, `get_name_1`, that method cannot access its objects attributes either (unless `self` is passed to it).)

However, AFTER the objects are both instantiated, the second object, `maze` can now recognise and access its creator object, `zeus`.

This behaviour has caused me some confusion and difficulties, as I was working on some code where everything was initialised and run from the `__init__` sequence - now I suppose that it is better to avoid that..

My questions:

1. Why is this the case?
2. Are problems that can arise through this best avoided by leaving instantiation, out of `__init__` calls?
3. Are there further design implications?
4. Passing `self` to a new instance, seems as though it could create problems, due to self-referencing, should this also be avoided?
5. Other interesting implications/ Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You shouldn't refer to global objects inside the class, but to the instance itself, i.e. `self`, and if you need anything else, pass it as arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_zeus_name_1()` is trying to access the global variable `zeus`, which has not yet been initialised at the moment when `get_zeus_name_1()` is called.

`get_zeus_name_2()` takes an argument (`scope`) and accesses that, which works. It doesn't try to access the global variable `zeus`.

Same story with `get_name_1()` and `get_name_2()`.

I think the key point is to understand how python executes this line:

```
zeus=Zeus()
```

This line says to python: execute the method `Zeus()` (which is another name for the `__init__(self)` method in the `Zeus` class), and then assign the object returned by that method to the global variable `zeus`.

Python first executes the method `Zeus()` and then, *after* the init method has finished executing and returned an object-instance of the Zeus class, python assigns that object to the global variable zeus. So the global variable zeus has not been defined until after the init method finishes, so get_name_1() and get_zeus_name_1() cannot access it.

get_name_2() and get_zeus_name_2() access the same object-instance of the Zeus class as get_name_1() and get_zeus_name_1() try to access, but they access it via a parameter that is passed to them, not via the global variable, so they don't run into the problem.

Here is a simpler example that demonstrates exactly the same problem:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.name = 'foobar'
...         print self.name
...         print foo.name
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
foobar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
>>>
```

The `print self.name` line works just fine (equivalent to get_name_2() and get_zeus_name_2()), but the `print foo.name` line crashes (equivalent to get_name_2() and get_zeus_name_2()).

Comment: good example - that really spells it out. But is it better practise to create a new object after the `__init__` has finished, or to do it within `__init__` and pass `self` in thus possibly running into circular reference.

Comment: Inside an `__init__` method it's probably safer to do: `child = Child()` and then `child.parent = self` like you suggest, to avoid a possible circular dependency if you do `child = Child(self)`. However, it still wouldn't make a circular dependency impossible. A better design might be one where the child object doesn't need to have a reference to its parent object.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it's because of Python nature - it executes source code "line by line". In this line: `zeus=Zeus()` you create an object and `__init__` method is called. When it executes there is no global `zeus` variable yet. I suppose you caught NameError: name 'zeus' is not defined (BTW, catching every exception is bad practice `except: ...`; instead you should catch only exceptions you expect; `except NameError: ...`).

You need to remember that in Python everything is happening in run-time. Here

```
x = 1 # x is just created, y 2 isn't created yet, you can't access it
y = 2 # y is just created, you can use it
```

This could also cause circular import, when module A imports module B, while module B imports something from module A, but module A isn't created yet - error.

In your case it'd be better to pass a link to original Zeus object to Maze object, like in `__init__`, and access it from Maze only after Zeus object is fully created.

Comment: Ok, I realised things happen in run-time, but I didn't think that the `zeus` global variable cannot be referenced/does not exist until the `__init__` call is complete (I thought that would be the first thing it does).. I guess that does explain this. So is it better design practise to instantiate `maze`, after the `zeus` `__init__` has finished (as a second line)? - or should I keep it in the `__init__` but pass through `self`.? Also i realise the `try/except` use ideology, it was just to illustrate the issue. cheers.

Comment: I don't know what option is better, it depends on what do you need. You could leave it in `__init__` and pass `self` to Maze `__init__`, it looks like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let see if I can make an example to help a bit.

If we want to work with a bunch of greek gods we need to start with a very simple `GreekGod` class:

```
class GreekGod(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

zeus = GreekGod('Zeus')
athena = GreekGod('Athena')
print zeus.name
```

If now we want to do more, for example give at each greek god his own [epithet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet), we need to add the epithet attribute to our class:

```
class GreekGod(object):

    def __init__(self, name, epithet):
        self.name = name
        self.epithet = epithet

    def get_catch_frase(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.epithet

zeus = GreekGod('Zeus', 'Father of the gods')
print zeus.get_catch_frase()  # -> Zeus Father of the gods
```

As you can see the method `get_catch_frase` return a string, does not print that string, this behaviour is expected when you call a method "get_something" because one would expect that something to be returnd, and nothing else.

I also hope you see the role of `self` which represents the object instance inside the class.

Comment: You forgot to assign `epithet` a value :)

Comment: Thanks, for clarification on how to I should use the "get_" prefix. But I don't see how you are answering my question?

Comment: @fraxel: Infact I didn't answer to your "question mark" questions (there were already good answers for those), but since neither get_name_1 or 2 had the correct approach which would have been `return self.name` and since you said to be new to python, I thought to show you that. But build a method with a simple `return self.name` would have been silly because you can simply use `zeus.name` when you want the name (and I wouldn't made things more complicate with private attributes and [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)), so I created the epithet variant above.

Comment: @Rik Poggi: yep :) thanks. Its actually really cool to get advice on correct style and approach, as well as trying to understand the actual background logic to the Python language. I'm finding their are a very large number of different approaches I can adopt to solve the same problems, but some turn out not to be so clean and sometimes become a tangle. Hence the desire to get a better feeling for what is and is not 'pythonic'!

Comment: @fraxel: [The Zen of Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228181/1132524) says something about that :)